# JPA Application based on Multiple Databases can not resolve DB of the related Entity

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish, jta

My app uses 3 other databases (MySQL) and 3 PUs on Glassfish 3.1. While retrieving data from database 'A' with relation (for example @OneToOne) from model from database 'B' an error occurs:

`SELECT command denied to user .. for table 'related_table'`

This error DOES NOT occur when I name each entity this way:
`@Table(name="db_name.table_name")`, but this is not a good option, because I use H2 Database for tests and H2 can not resolve such naming.

[edit]

Important thing: app worked perfectly without this 'special table naming' in @Table, before I reinstalled my Glassfish - same version and I have nothing changed in Glassfish Settings for this purpose before..

Comment: which is one reason why many people recommend using orm.xml for schema information, and you have a different orm.xml for each schema

Comment: Is there a difference between using orm.xml except of persistence.xml in this case?

Comment: you don't use orm.xml INSTEAD OF persistence.xml. You use it instead of some annotations in classes, and the persistence-unit should point to the required orm.xml file

Comment: Understood. So isn't there a way to resolve this problem using annotations only? Important thing is that before I reinstalled Glassfish everything worked perfectly using just @Table(name="table_name")